# Intellisense for JQuery in Dreamweaver and Delphi4PHP

Tags: php, jquery, delphi, dreamweaver, delphi4php

For all our AJAX programming we tend to use JQuery.

I would like to know if there is a way to enable Intellisense functionality in *Dreamweaver CS3* and *Delphi4PHP* to work with JQuery and its plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Delph4PHP, but Dreamweaver CS3 has very limited JavaScript code hinting (Dreamweaver's version of  "Intellisense"). Basically, it has hinting for built in JavaScript objects such as Array, Math, Number, Object, etc. YOu can see what code hints it has by going into a JavaScript file and at an empty are hit CTRL+Space and you'll see what is available. It doesn't have any dynamic code hinting for JavaScript, that is, if you do the following:

var d = new Date();

And type (note the dot/period at the end):

d.

You do not get code hints for the Date object. Note: for array, date, and string objects if you name your variables with the appropriate suffix, then the hard coded code hints can work for those objects. The suffixes are _array, _date and _str  and are clumsy at best.

Dreamweaver CS4 did introduce some dynamic code hinting, so when you create a Date object you should get code hinting for the methods Date object. Similar is true for the jQuery object; however, the hinting is based upon the jQuery named object not on the $ object and there are some other limitations as well, but since you're concerned with CS3, that's not too relevant now.

There is an extension that adds some code hinting for jQuery, but it's only for the jQuery object and not for any of the plugins (as far as I know): [jQuery API extension for Dreamweaver](http://xtnd.us/dreamweaver/jquery). Also, I believe that these hints are hard coded and not dynamic in nature is if you assign the $ object to another variable name, you won't get code hints for that new variable name.